# sass - grouping selectors

Tags: css, sass

I have this sass code:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    &:hover {
    color: #fff;
    }
}
```

This output:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

But I want to be:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

How can I use the same property in the parent and the child without repeating the parent with sass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```css
$white: #fff;

.navbar-default {
 .navbar-brand {
  color: $white;
  &:hover {
   color: $white;
  }
 }
 .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: $white;
 }
}
```

Comment: This is an elegant and clear solution, not overly-complicated (like mine).

Comment: Both answers are good (@richfinelli & @Karl Dawson), thanks a lot! But sincerely I don't see any advantage in this case, so I will keep it with standard CSS, just with the color in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not really possible to exactly do what you're asking only with the ampersand. The ampersand (&) always gets replaced with the parent selector. In your case, parent selectorS. But what you could do is remove the `:hover` from the first selector and toss in an `@extend`. I created a new selector called ".primary-color" which will hold the color.

```
.primary-color {
  color: white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    @extend .primary-color;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    &:hover {
        @extend .primary-color;
    }
}
```

This compiles to this CSS:

```
.primary-color, .navbar-default .navbar-brand, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

@extend is a little different than a mixin in how it compiles the CSS. I'm not in love with how it gives you the extra '.primary-color' class that I created, but other than that you sort of get what you want.

Probably a little more complicated of a setup than it needs to be though. I would just add the extra parent selector like you mentioned in your question to get the results your looking for.

This is an article I wrote on the sass ampersand that might be helpful. https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

Comment: If you change `.primary-color` to `%primary-color` (a Sass placeholder) then use it as `@extend: %primary-color`, you save the unused class being output :)

Comment: @Karl Dawsom - that's much better. i thought there was something like that!

Comment: no worries, and thanks for your ampersand article - I'd read that earlier on in the week in case I'd forgotten a trick or two with their use.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the redundant `:hover:hover` you can simplify it to:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    &, &:hover {
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

output:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand, 
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```